# Router stops giving internet randomly while modem continues to work

Tags: router, internet, dd-wrt, cable-modem

My internet provider had installed in my house an Alcatel modem (FTTH).
I have a dd-wrt TPLINK router.

For months my internet was working perfectly having the modem (bridged mode set by ISP) connected to the WAN port of the router. The router was receiving a WAN ip and my devices were configured behind the dhcp of the dd-wrt with private network ips.

Since a couple of days a strange thing happens. My internet just stops working. I am connected without problem to the router but I just don't receive any internet at all. When I connect directly on the modem everything works fine!

So, if I restart the modem or if I go to the ddwrt's status->WAN page and I do a "dhcp release" and get a new (external) IP I get internet again... then again the same problem. I haven't noticed a time pattern. Sometimes the disconnect can happen in 20 minutes, sometimes in more.

The problem has me really confused. The only thing I can think of (after having eliminated the possibility of a hardware defect -at least from the router side- not so sure about the modem) is that the provider / modem for some reason changes the IP frequently and my router doesn't keep up, that's why I have to "force" a dhcp release inside ddwrt. Does that make any sense?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there anything strange in the logbook of your router?